# How does the arbotix_driver publish /odom topic?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use rqt_graph to chech nodes and topics, I find the arbotix node publish the /odom topic, but I cann't find out how it does this in arbotix_driver? Anyone can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247047/how-does-the-arbotix_driver-publish-/odom-topic?/) by [JasonLi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28416/jasonli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publisher declaration: https://github.com/vanadiumlabs/arbotix_ros/blob/indigo-devel/arbotix_python/src/arbotix_python/diff_controller.py#L94

Odometry calculation and publishing to tf and topic: https://github.com/vanadiumlabs/arbotix_ros/blob/indigo-devel/arbotix_python/src/arbotix_python/diff_controller.py#L125-L173

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0